# Como criar rotas privadas com react js

Tags: react-router, react-dom

Estou precisando criar robtas privadas que so podem ser acessadas se o usuario recebeu um token valido e caso ele n tenha validado va para pagina de login.
Vi um codigo em outra pergunta mas o mesmo n funciona comigo por conta, acredito eu, que da atualização da biblioteca

```
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

const isAuthenticated = () => localStorage.getItem('token');

export const PrivateRouter = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={props => 
                    isAuthenticated() ? (
                        <Component {...props} />
                    ) : (
                        <Redirect to={{pathname:"/login", state: {from:props.location}}} />
                    )
                }
        />
    )
}
```

Porem esse "Redirect" não funciona, ele diz que não exite nada de Redirect na biblioteca

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você deve estar usando a versão 6 do react-router-dom.
Vai no teu package.json e confirma se você está com versão acima de 6:

```
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
```

Caso esteja, na versão 6 dessa lib, não existe mais Redirect mesmo, o similar seria o Navigate:

```
<Navigate to="/login" />
```